# viewing different columns of two tables in a single table using subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables T1 and T2 -
T1-columns(c1, c2)
T2-columns(c2, c4)
c2 is the primary key of T1 and a foreign key in T2. I want to return a record which contains `T1.c1` and `T2.c4` where `T2.c4= 'some value'`  using subqueries. So, I wrote a subquery -
`SELECT c1 FROM T1 WHERE c2=(SELECT c2 FROM T2 WHERE c4 = 'some value')`
Is there a way to view both these columns (T1.c1, T2.c4) in a single table with subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `c4` you want in the result is `'some value'` (if it exists):

```
SELECT c1, 'some value' c4 
FROM T1 
WHERE c2 = (SELECT c2 FROM T2 WHERE c4 = 'some value')
```

This will work only if the subquery:

```
SELECT c2 FROM T2 WHERE c4 = 'some value'
```

returns only 1 row.

But this requirement could be better resolved with a join:

```
SELECT T1.c1, T2.c4 
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON T2.c2 = T1.c1
WHERE T2.c4 = 'some value';
```